# Plot density for ~20 x 20 x 20 cubes

Tags: python, r

I am looking for a good way to plot a density plot (in Python or R) that shows the space regularly explored by a simulated protein.  The data set consists of densities within many 5x5x5 cubes, like this:

```
x      y    z    density
-4    -3    51    0 
-4    -3    56    0.523343
     ...
121    92    81    1 
121    92    86    0.01
```

(x, y, z) represents coordinates in 3D, and it is the point at the bottom left corner of a cube. Each cube is 5x5x5 in size. There is no overlap between any of two cubes. There are about 10k cubes total.

The `density` column is the color I would like to assign to each cube. The numbers are in a range of 0 to 1.

I'm also open to other plotting methods. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the goal of the visualization? To show overall structure? To highlight extremes? To make an aesthetically pleasing graphic? This is a large amount of data to show directly (let alone the challenges of showing in 3D), so it may be more fruitful to start with the point you want to communicate and work back from there.

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you very much for your comment. Do you mean a full table? I can send that to you via email or message if you'd like.

Comment: @JonSpring Thank you very much for your comments. The primary point of this visualization is to show the space regularly explored by a simulated protein in a density map - like plot. I could not locate a proper name for this, but would love to learn your opinion.

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://plot.ly/r/3d-surface-plots/#multiple-surfaces.  Plotly is a javascript library with interface packages in both R and Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 10k cubes I guess plotly's mesh3d or 3d-surface plots (as mentioned by @Jon Spring) will be too computationally intensive.

I'm not sure if this is an option for you but I'd go with a scatter3d plot like this:

[image]

```
library(plotly)

n <- 100

cubes <- data.frame(
  x = rnorm(n, 0, 200),
  y = rnorm(n, 0, 200),
  z = rnorm(n, 0, 200),
  density = runif(n, 0, 1)
)

p <- plot_ly(cubes, x = ~x, y = ~y, z = ~z, color = ~density, type = "scatter3d", mode = "markers", colors = colorRamp(c("blue", "lightblue", "chartreuse3", "yellow", "red")), marker = list(symbol = 'square', size = 4))
p

# optional: save plot as a HTML file
library(htmlwidgets)
saveWidget(p, file="myScatter3dPlot.html", selfcontained = TRUE)
```

Increasing `n` to 10k runs smooth. The downside here is, that the symbols displayed are flat squares and the given datapoints (x, y, z) are their center (you could calculate an offset from the bottom left corner). Also the square size and colors probably need to be adapted to your usecase.

Please see some further information [here](https://plot.ly/r/3d-scatter-plots/) and [here](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#scatter3d).

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. Beautiful plotting. Let me get back to after I try these two solutions out.

Comment: @Helene Did you try them by now? Just remembered due to your recent question.

Answer (score 1):

The functions in the `misc3d` package (built on the `rgl` interface to OpenGL) seem nice for this.

### make up data

In the absence of data to play with, I used a multivariate normal density

```
dd <- expand.grid (x=1:21,y=1:21,z=1:21)
dd[,1:3] <- scale(dd[,1:3])
library(mvtnorm)
S <- matrix(c(0.5,0.1,-0.1,0.1,2,0.7,-0.1,0.7,1),3,3)
dd$dens <- dmvnorm(dd[,1:3],mean=c(0,0,0),sigma=S)
```

### reshape data

`misc3d::image3d()` needs a 3D array to work with; using `reshape2::acast()` to do the job

```
library(reshape2)
v <- acast(dd,x~y~z, value.var="dens")
```

### make the picture

```
library(viridisLite)  ## optional: prettier colour palette
library(misc3d)
## function to extract dim names for x, y, z axes
d <- function(i) as.numeric(dimnames(v)[[i]])
image3d(v,x=d(1),y=d(2),z=d(3),
        sprites=TRUE,  ## (default)
        col=viridis(256))
contour3d(v,x=d(1),y=d(2),z=d(3),level=c(0.01,0.03),
          alpha=0.2,add=TRUE)
box3d()
rgl.snapshot("dens3d.png")
```

I was having some trouble with taking the snapshot (maybe something about my system), so settled for a screenshot.  Rendering with 10,000 points is a *little* slow on an old MacBook Pro, but not too bad. You can experiment with colours, `sprites=TRUE` vs `FALSE`, contours ...

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I am going to give it a try and get back to you. Nice plot!